# Notices are confusing on mobile web

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, mobile-web

Which answer does this notice belong to?

> [image]

If you said the one that starts with “possible”, you are wrong. The post notice belongs to the answer above that (not shown in the screenshot). It is below the comments, which does not make sense to me. It should look like it is attached to the answer it is on not the answer below that or the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, post notices show up *below* post but *above* its comments on the main site, IIRC. Maybe mobile site needs to follow the same style.

Comment: That's essentially what the OP is proposing ... I'd have posted this as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel I _did_ post this as a comment, but then thought it might get removed cuz it looks like an answer. Erm..

Comment: I can confirm it's for questions that the notice is **between** the post and its comments on mobile web.

Comment: Starting with the next prod build, post notices will appear between the body of the answer and the comments, just as you suggested. Thanks!